# Setting up asp.net Razor page UserManager for Dependency Injection

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, usermanager

I understand UserManager for an asp.net Razor page is defined via dependency injection and so I have a page as follows:

```
public class SetupModel : PageModel
{
      public SetupModel(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
      {
      }
```

Unsurprisingly with no other config in Program.cs this page blows up with 'InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager'

**My question is how to setup UserManager in Program.cs for DI?**

ChatGPT says it is simply:

```
builder.services.AddScoped<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();
```

but this results in an error: *"Some services are not able to be constructed....Unable to resolve service for type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore"*

The only Authentication code in Program.cs comes from the boilerplate Visual Studio creates for Authentication: Microsoft Identity Platform, shown below. What do I have to modify or add to config UserManager?

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});

builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
     .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
```

P.S. I do see the SSO user in @User.Identity?.Name! so Authentication is working but now I would like to see the roles that user is in.

---

Per Tiny Wang's advice below my code now looks like this for a .Net 8 Razor page app using Microsoft Identity Platform with https. It results in an exception: *The service collection cannot be modified because it is read-only.*

```
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    
    // Add services to the container.
    // From StackOverflow Tiny Wang
     builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
        .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
    
    builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options => {
        options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
    });
    builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
    
    var app = builder.Build();
    
    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment()) {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }
    
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    
    app.UseRouting();
    
    app.UseAuthorization();
    
    app.MapRazorPages();
    app.MapControllers();
    
    app.Run();
```

and my appsettings.json file:

```
{
  // This is for SSO using VS Authentication/Identity Platform
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "obfuscated.com",
    "TenantId": "2dc6507f-***obfuscated***524a1",
    "ClientId": "fbc512fe-***obfuscated****",
    "ClientSecret": "gxU8Q***obfuscated***",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
  "DownstreamApi": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    "Scopes": "User.ReadWrite.All"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

and my nuget versions:

```
microsoft.identity.web.ui\1.16.0\
microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.openidconnect\6.0.24\
microsoft.identity.web\1.16.0\
microsoft.graph\4.43.0\
microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.jwtbearer\6.0.24\
microsoft.identity.web.microsoftgraph\1.16.0\
```

---

For anyone following this thread the final solution was to upgrade all nupkg to the latest version and then replace microsoft.identity.web.microsoftgraph with Microsoft.Identity.Web.GraphServiceClient

Comment: Those links do not provide any specific examples of code for my problem. The first is for an auth scheme called Individual User Accounts which I am not using. The second link is mostly about setting up Entra which of-course I have already done or SSO would not work. The third talks about 'Web Apps that signs in Users' (using Entra Admin Center) but no code examples. What I am really looking for is code similar to that first link that is for Microsoft Identity Platform - not Individual User Accounts.

Comment: Here is the most relevant link, IF ONLY they provided some sample code with it: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Comment: Hi @CsharpSqlGuy, just like what you can see in the link you appead, the `UserManager` Class is from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` while `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp` in your code is from `Microsoft.Identity.Web`, `UserManager` is used for Asp.net core default Identity while `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp` is based on Azure Identity. So that they are different. You mentioned you are using SSO, so I deduce you are now trying to use Azure identity, so that I recomment you using Graph API to manage user information, as Azure Identity doesn't provide `UserManager` service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code snippet, you had code below which means you are using Azure AD as the authentication scheme in your asp.net core web app, so that we are not able to use the `UserManager` which is a service provided by Asp.net core default identity. In your scenario, you can use [Graph API for Users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/users?view=graph-rest-1.0) to access and manage user profile.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
  .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
```

Here's a sample for integrating Graph API SDK into your app and use the SDK to call API.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy.
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
```

Then in the PageModel, inject GraphServiceClient to call graph api.

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;
    private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;
    public string? OfficeInfo { get; set; }

    public IndexModel(GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient, ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
    {
        _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        var me = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
        OfficeInfo = me.OfficeLocation;
    }
}
```

By the way, we need to add in appsettings.json with `client secret` and `DownstreamApi`.

```
"AzureAd": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
  "Domain": "tenant_id",
  "TenantId": "tenant_id",
  "ClientId": "client_id",
  "ClientSecret": "client_secret",
  "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
},
"DownstreamApi": {
  "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
  "Scopes": "User.ReadWrite.All"
},
```

Here's the nuget packages I used. Pls note, `Microsoft.Graph` in Version 5.x would [bring differences in coding](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md).

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="6.0.24" NoWarn="NU1605" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="6.0.24" NoWarn="NU1605" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="1.16.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="1.16.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph" Version="1.16.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph" Version="4.43.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

[image]

In my code snippet above, I'm using [this API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) which requires `User.Read` permission, so I need to add it in Azure.

[image]

====================== With .net 8 and Graph SDK v5.x ============

We need to change the nuget package versions and modify the API calling code. The rest are the same.

```
public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
    var me = await _graphServiceClient.Me.GetAsync();
    OfficeInfo = me.OfficeLocation;
}

<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="8.0.0" NoWarn="NU1605" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="8.0.0" NoWarn="NU1605" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="2.15.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="2.15.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.DownstreamApi" Version="2.15.2" />
    <!--<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph" Version="2.15.2" />-->
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph" Version="5.44.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.GraphServiceClient" Version="2.15.2" />
</ItemGroup>
```

[image]

Comment: That is a brilliant response Tiny Wang! One reason I love it is because you provide the detail about which library version numbers you are using. So often a Microsoft code example does not tell you this important detail.

Unfortunately I get an exception: The service collection cannot be modified because it is read-only.

I have copied your code exactly into a new Razor App .Net 8 with Microsoft Identity Platform with https. The only addition I needed was to appsettings.json for Downstreamapi and ClientSecret.

Comment: I test with a app created by default template from VS 2022 and choosing "Microsoft identity platform" as the authentication type when creating the project. There might be some differences between different .net versions. And about the Downstreamapi and ClientSerect, they are from Azure AD knowledge, since you mentioned you already sign in successfully, I assume you already configured them all.

Comment: Anyway, you can follow [this section](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-1-Call-MSGraph/README.md#register-the-client-web-app-webapp-openidconnect-dotnet-graph-v2) for setting redirect url, add client secret.

Comment: And about adding API permissions, you might make sure which API you are required to use, then in the corresponding API document, get to know which API permission is required(pls note you need to use the Delegated API permission because you are trying to call API on behalf of the signed-in user). Then in AAD page, add the required API permissions. Some of the permissions requires admin consent, click to consent the permissions if required.

Comment: I added my new code per your prior advice to my original post. I think it matches your code exactly, especially the library version numbers. And yes, I have Entra setup so ClientSecret is defined, etc. In API Persmission Microsoft Graph was already added with User.Read and Admin Permission = No.

Comment: Tiny: was your app .Net 8 as mine is? Maybe I should try .Net 7?

Comment: I'm testing with .net 8 version. Net 7 might be better for matching my code snippet. I'm afraid .net 8 can only support Graph SDK with V5.x and Microsoft.Identity.Web with v2.x

Comment: @CsharpSqlGuy I had a test with .net 8, we need to change the nuget package versions. I reproduced your issue by using the nuget packages for .net 6 app, so that pls using the nuget packages for .net 8 test would fix the exception.

Comment: Two things: 1) that link for 2-1-Call-MsGraph was great - just the kind of code I was looking for (even though it was not Razor pages.) I downloaded and it ran fine which means my Entra Setup is good. 2) I upgraded to latest nuget versions and now get a 'cannot load Graph.Core 3.1.8.0' exception. The versions are: JwtBearer v8.0, OpenIDConnect v8.0, Graph v5.44, Identity.Web v2.15.2, Web.Downstream v 2.15.2, Web.UI v2.15.2, Web.MicrosoftGraph v2.17.1. Note that Graph v5.44 contains Graph.Core 3.1.8.0.

Comment: SUCCESS! After upgrading every nuget package to the lastest I still had an exception 'Could not load type 'Microsoft.Graph.IAuthenticationProviderOption'. The fix for that was to replace Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph with Microsoft.Identity.Web.GraphServiceClient. Can't thank you enough Tiny - you offer truly superb help.