_graphServiceClient.Me.GetAsync() throws IUserRequestBuilder does not contain GetAsync()
I want to obtain data from GraphServiceClient according to this example
However, the line
var user = await _graphServiceClient.Me.GetAsync();

throws the following error:

IUserRequestBuilder does not contain a definition for GetAsync

I've installed the following NuGet packages:

Microsoft.Identity.Web 2.17.5
Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph 2.17.5
Microsoft.Graph 4.36.0

The di is set up like this
string[] initialScopes = Configuration.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' ');

services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureB2C"))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(options =>
        {
            var section = Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd");
            options.RedirectUri = section.GetValue<string>("RedirectUri") + section.GetValue<string>("CallbackPath");
        })
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();


Use Microsoft.Graph v5.x. The syntax of v4.x (in your case 4.36.0) is different.

Thank you. Now it throws a TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Graph.IAuthenticationProviderOption' from assembly 'Microsoft.Graph.Core, Version=3.1.10.0 error....

using Microsoft.Identity.Web.GraphServiceClient to replace Microsoft.Graph and Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph

Thanks again. Weirdly enough, I can't add using Microsoft.Identity.Web.GraphServiceClient; is it throws a The type or namespace GraphServiceClient does not exist in the namespace Microsoft.Identity.Web.

Pls allow me to show my codes below, which could be well-read in answer mode. It's hard to read in comments. does not exist in the namespace Microsoft.Identity.Web maybe we can clean the project or the soltuion?

Here's my nuget packages using Graph SDK v5, then we can write codes like _graphServiceClient.Me.GetAsync();
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="8.0.0" NoWarn="NU1605" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="8.0.0" NoWarn="NU1605" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="2.15.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="2.15.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.DownstreamApi" Version="2.15.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.GraphServiceClient" Version="2.15.2" />
</ItemGroup>

If we want to use Graph SDK v4, then we can use _graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();, and the nuget packages should downgrade version, my sample using
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph" Version="4.43.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Client" Version="4.52.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="1.26.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph" Version="1.26.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="1.26.0" />


Does this mean, you don't need Microsoft.Graph at all?

here's a description for the nuget package upgradation: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Identity.Web.GraphServiceClient/Readme.md   and yes, we use GraphServiceClient in SDK V5

Despite all or your great help, it still does not work, as it throws a new error MsalUiRequiredException: No account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent call . I've seen this on Stack Overflow, but I don't think the answers fit. Also it is nowhere mentioned in the tutorials here and there

You should call AcquireTokenInteractive() instead of AcquireTokenSilent(). For further details take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/scenario-desktop-acquire-token-interactive?tabs=dotnet

Thank you very much. Unfortunately, the link shows an example for a desktop app. And the tutorials I followed for asp.net don't even mention AcquireTokenInteractive or AcquireTokenSilent. I'll dig around and see if I can find an example that mentions this for asp mvc.

MsalUiRequiredException: No account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent call I suffered from this error for a long time too. Yes, when we call Ms Graph API, even via the SDK, it still requires the authentication and get the access token (EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi), using SDK helped us to not require to add bearer token into request header manually. in our scenario, we need to sign into the app in advance then we could use _graphServiceClient.Me.GetAsync(). Without authentication, we would get this exception.

Then the topic come back to that, Azure AD realized SSO by default, so that when we once signed in successfully, and try to sign in again in a short time, browser would redirect to microsoft identity platform to trigger the sign in but the identity platform would found that this account already signed in, then it would redirect back to our web app directly and set a cookie in the website, once we visit our website and found there's such a cookie, our website will recogize as there already a user signed in.

However, when we debug the app locally, we always shut down and restart the app again, each time we restart the app, a new session would establish which is different with the formor one, the browser think user has signed in so that it bypass the auth but to the server app it found the session doesn't match which is equal to no login, so that it can't help to auth the Graph SDK, then we got exception MsalUiRequiredException: No account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent call. Solution is clean browser cache or open website via private window. But it brings much trouble.

Then I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73295284  it's really a good idea, because we do require to sign in each time when testing locally for using the Graph SDK.

In short, await _graphServiceClient.Me.GetAsync(); requires users to sign in so that the app could know who is Me, and Graph SDK requires authorization as well after user sign in via the access token. But due to the SSO mechanism, our web app will remember the login information but doesn't match the new session, so that the app doesn't redirect us to sign in when we do require to sign in when a new session established. So I found that work around for solving the new exception you faced. I found a sample I test before with more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78099667/14574199
